# operator>>: должна возвращать значение

Tags: c++, функции, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Не могу понять что компилятору не нравится - проблема в названии
Заголовки подключены все

Ниже convert.h

```
class Convert {
private:
 string currency_in, currency_out;
 double amountOfMoney_In;
public:
Convert() { }
Convert(double amountOfMoneyIn): amountOfMoney_In(amountOfMoneyIn) { }
Convert(double amountOfMoneyIn, string currencyIn, string currencyOut) 
    {
    this->amountOfMoney_In = amountOfMoneyIn;
    this->currency_in = currencyIn;
    this->currency_out = currencyOut;
    }
friend istream& operator>> (istream& in, Convert& object);
};

istream& operator >> (istream& in, Convert& object)
{
    in >> object.amountOfMoney_In;
    in >> object.currency_in;
    in >> object.currency_out;
}
```

main.cpp

```
Convert var1;
cin >> var1;
```

Comment: operator>> должен возвращать значение. Ваша функция возвращает `istream&` как указано в сигнатуре?

Answer (score 3):

```
istream& operator >> (istream& in, Convert& object)
{
    in >> object.amountOfMoney_In;
    in >> object.currency_in;
    in >> object.currency_out;
}
```

Что тут описано? Оператор, возвращающий `istream&`. И где же возврат этого значения? Где оператор `return`?

Дальше все ясно? :)